# What's the part of speech for power?

Tags: nouns

"Your father, on the other hand, favored a mahogany wand. Eleven inches. Pliable. A little more **power** and excellent for transfiguration.”
(Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is ‘power’ a predicative adjective? There’s a usage as a modifier in [Oxford](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/power?q=power) - a *power* drill -, yet I don’t find the adjective use. What’s the part of speech in the sentence?

Comment: It's an ordinary noun; Mr. Ollivander is saying (very elliptically) that the wand *possesses* or *permits* or perhaps *confers* a little more power.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The section “a mahogany wand. Eleven inches. Pliable. A little more power” says, in effect, that a pliable, 11-inch, mahogany wand has more power than some other wand.
The statement is made somewhat elliptically so that it more closely resembles the manner in which some people speak in fits and starts, or in incomplete phrases and parts of sentences; or perhaps so that it looks like dialogue typical of a given speaker.

The noun *[power](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/power?q=power)* is the object in the SVO sequence  “wand has power”.  The applicable sense of *power* may be
1, “the ability or capacity to do something or act in a particular way”, or 3, “physical strength and force exerted by something”, or a mix of those two senses.

Answer (score 0):

The shopowner is speaking in telegram style. You have to add: (Your father's wand) had a little more power and was excellent for transfiguration.

"Power" is a normal noun.